# I got 'ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:'

Tags: python, keras, artificial-intelligence, valueerror

When I train the ML model that other team members had no problem with,

but I got 'ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:'

Total error statement is below

`ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'lstm/lstm_cell/kernel:0', 'lstm/lstm_cell/recurrent_kernel:0', 'lstm/lstm_cell/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0', 'dense_2/kernel:0', 'dense_2/bias:0'].`

and below is the block of Jupyter Notebook that makes error

```
model.layers[2]
model.layers[2].set_weights([embedding_matrix])
model.layers[2].trainable = False

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

epochs = 10
number_pics_per_bath = 3
steps = len(train_descriptions)//number_pics_per_bath

for i in range(epochs):
    generator = data_generator(train_descriptions, train_features, wordtoix, max_length, number_pics_per_bath)
    model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=1)
    model.save('C:/MyAI/archive/model_' + str(i) + '.h5')
```

i think you also want to see my total code. it is easy, because I almost copied the code of below github link

https://github.com/hlamba28/Automatic-Image-Captioning/blob/master/Automatic%20Image%20Captioning.ipynb

because I don't have the same path or name of file like github,
I changed a little bit of above github code, but i did not change the logical part of code.

and my other team member said he had no problem with our code (that is changed a little bit), and showed me that ML model is trained well and make result intended.